# Powershell codes throwing errors on Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I've added the following line of Powershell codes in Jenkins and it's throwing some errors, although it's working fine when I'm trying to execute it via Powershell ISE on the same desktop/machine.

I have configured the Jenkins service logon and the user ID got correct permission.

Kindly advise.

```
servers = Get-Content "C:\tmp\script\updated\SessionHost.txt"

  foreach ($server in $servers)
  {
    $FolderWindows = Start-Process -FilePath "\\$server\C$\Temp" -WindowStyle Maximized
 }

Error Message on Jenkins:

Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Server execution 
failed.At C:\tmp\script\updated\MainTaiwanUAT.ps1:385 char:22
+     $FolderWindows = Start-Process -FilePath "\\$server\C$\Temp" 
-WindowS ...
+                      
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOp 
   erationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.C 
   ommands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: have you included powershell path in your jenkins path settings?

Comment: Yes. i have included the powershell script path. Eg. powershell -File C:\tmp\script\updated\script.ps1